# Separate POST access urls for same resource

Tags: django, tastypie

I need to create separate POST methods for user creation and user authentication

eg:http://localhost:8000/registerUser which takes email,name and password to register a user and another url

eg:http://localhost:8000/authenticateUser whcih takes the email and password to authenticate the user

Can I do this with by overriding "override_url" or the "dispatch"  method ? Or anyother way

Comment: Why don't you just create 2 resources?

Comment: Is there a point to creating 2 resources when the data is the same ?

Comment: What does authenticateUser do? REST authentication happens in the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you are looking for is the `prepend_url` function, see [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=override#prepend-urls). You could use it like this:

```
class AuthenticateUser(Resource)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = "authenticateUser"

    def prepend_urls(self):
        #add the cancel url to the resource urls
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<pk>\w[\w/-]*)/register%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('register'), name="api_authenticate_register"),
        ]

    def register(self, request, **kwargs):
        # check request
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        # handle your request here, register user
        return self.create_response(request,  <some method>)
```

With this, you could call it like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/authenticateUser # to authenticate
http://localhost:8000/authenticateUser/register # to register
```

Another option would be, to just create two resources (on inheriting from the other) and just change the `resource_name` in the meta class

Comment: Thanks wii try it out

Comment: How can I access the request data? `request.data['email']`  gives me AttributeError: request

Comment: Usually, you can access it by: `request.POST.get('email', None)`

Comment: Thanks for the info. But that didnt work. Looks like reques From the documentation - It’s possible that a request can come in via POST with an empty POST dictionary – if, say, a form is requested via the POST HTTP method but does not include form data. Therefore, you shouldn’t use if request.POST to check for use of the POST method; instead, use if request.method == "POST". I am currently accesing thru request.body and then converting it to a dictionary